# Water is running out the front of my car were the radiator is can that be a hose ? 2006 vw beetle

Tags: cooling-system, radiator, coolant-leak

When i put the fluid in it just ran right out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Pictures of the leak (especially the color of the fluid) would help. Note that you can sometimes trace the path of the colored fluid and backtrack to the original leak.

Answer (score 3):

If you see a small puddle of clear, colorless water under the front of your Beetle, it could be condensation from the air conditioner. That's normal and not a leak.

The 2006 Beetle uses a special pink or purple coolant made for VWs. Please see the photo below (credit: newbeetle.org) and identify object #16. That is your coolant reservoir. The coolant level must be maintained between the upper and lower lines on that reservoir. That reservoir is the only place where coolant should be added.

If this is where you added coolant and it ran out, then the thin black hose that connects the coolant reservoir to the radiator has become disconnected and it must be repaired or replaced.

[image]